# Regular Expression- why does .* match all lines in a file?

Tags: regex

Apologies for the seeming triviality of the question in advance. Seeing as that the . character matches any character except an end-of-line character, why does running *grep .* foo.bar* return every line in the file? I would assume that it only ought to return the first line before it reaches the end-of-line, does not match it and conks out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

grep matches every line against the given regex separately

Comment: Oh. Thanks for your answer. On the same note, is that true for any regex engine for eg. if I use a regex library in a programming language?

Comment: depends on the mode you are using. most versions of regex have multi-line mode, in which `.` is used to match all characters except newline, so `[.\n]` should match all characters including newline.

Comment: Well, `.*` will match at every *position* of a file, but in general regex engines start looking for matches at the point the previous match ended. Since (as you say) `.` doesn't usually match a newline character this means engines start looking again at the beginning of every line.

Comment: I may be wrong, but why do I get the feeling that you are both saying different things. When I ran this in php- preg_match(".*","Hi\nBye",$matches) and checked the size of the $matches array, it returned only "Hi" like what I think BillyMoon says. Gareth, if I understood you right you say that both "Hi" and "Bye" will be matched?